# Trying to use .map(String) to convert large array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to use `.map(String)` on a large array of Integers to convert them all to Strings. When I console logged it, it returned many Integers as Strings but at the bottom of the console there was the message: (...100 more items).

After they were converted, it also added a lot of whitespace to the array. 
I am looking for a way to be able to immediately view all my converted Integers as Strings, & remove the whitespace too.

I thought using node `mycode.js > formattedcode.txt` would work to show the full array at once, but it returned the same (... 100 more items) message at the bottom of the text file.
Instead of converting the Integers to Strings in smaller chunks.. I was looking for a programmatic solution for the conversion and removing whitespace.

```
console.log(blockedOffers.map(String).trim());

node mycode.js > formattedcode.txt
```

Comment: Maybe you want `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: do you have an example of the (some small) data and the wanted outcome?

Comment: `Array.prototype` does not have a property called `trim`. Is that a function you added, or is `blockedOffers` not an array?

Comment: JSON.stringify worked perfectly.. thank you

Comment: An small example could be: var blockedOffers = [5937927, 5938002,5940390, 5942079, 5949800, 5953944, 5954279]
and .trim returns ".trim() is not a function".
Using 'typeof blockedOffers' revealed that it is an object... not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript already has built in functionality that achieves just that, assuming you are running it with node, you would do something along the lines of:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const yourArray = ["test","test2"];
fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+"/fileName.json",JSON.stringify(yourArray));
```

JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, JSON is a lightweight format for storing and transporting data.

Comment: **UPDATE**
This worked for me:  
    `var numArray = [56, 23, 45, 15, 63];
    var myArray = numArray.map(String);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray));`

Answer (score 0):

You can try plain javascript join() and split()

```
blockedOffers.join(',').split(',')
```

Comment: While JSON.stringify worked.. the plain javascript solution you proposed still returned (... 103 more items)